# elFinder override 'rm' PHP

Tags: javascript, php, elfinder

I am using elFinder to manage assets for a web site and it's default functionality works great; however I need to add some additional logic to several of the PHP functions which resides in on of my Controllers.

The place that I would like the logic to be added is `<elfinder_Dir>/PHP/elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.php` specifically in the function `_unlink($path)` before a file is actually removed I would like to call out to another class to destroy the database entries for this asset.

The original function looks like this:

```
protected function _unlink($path) {
    return @unlink($path);
}
```

When I try to add code like the following:

```
protected function _unlink($path) {
    var_dump($path);
    return @unlink($path);
}
```

OR

```
//top of file...
use controllers\ResourceManager;

//OR
//include <pathToResourceManager>

//...

protected function _unlink($path) {
    ResourceManager::delteFromDB();
    return @unlink($path);
}
```

I receive this alert on the screen:

[image: MalformedBackend]

I also noticed that when that message is given, the header in my "Network" tab shows a Response Header Content-type of `text/html` instead of `application/json` as expected by the JS portion of elFinder.

Why is the header Content-type being changed when I add custom logic?
Is there a better way to add this functionality to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my question turned out to be pretty straight forward.

1) `error_reporting(0);` was squashing all of my errors related to using the proper namespace-ing for my files, I changed this to `error_reporting(E_ALL)` so I could see the real problem.

2) The files needed to be added to a `namespace`, since I used the same namespace I did not have any extra `include_once()` calls.

Next I had to add replace this line:

```
$class = 'elFinderVolume'.(isset($o['driver']) ? $o['driver'] : '');
```

With:

```
$class = __NAMESPACE__ . '\\elFinderVolume'.(isset($o['driver']) ? $o['driver'] : '');
```

Which allows the driver (which is now in the namespace) to be loaded properly.

Once these changes were made, all is well, I can add my own logic where I please.